# Appending Option Elements Into Select Failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-l-0">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <select disabled class="kurir">
        <option select="selected"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <select disabled class="tarif">
        <option select="selected"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my javascript :

```
$(".kurir").change(function() {

    var json_url = "some url here";

    $.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
        var tarif_items = "";
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            tarif_items += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
            alert (key); // I can see the key value
            alert (val); // I can see the val value
        });
    });

    $(this).closest(".row").find(".tarif").css("background-color", "red"); // I can see there's background color
    $(this).closest(".row").find(".tarif").prop("disabled", false); // I can see the select is active now
    $(this).closest(".row").find(".tarif").append(tarif_items); // but I don't see this works, why?

});
```

why `tarif_items` cannot be appended into select element?

Comment: Put the 'var tarif_items = "";' declaration outside the $.getJSON funciton

Comment: because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and so your code to append tarif_items is running before the `$.getJSON` code has completed. Put the last three lines of your code within the `$.getJSON` call

Answer (score 2):

That is because `tarif_items` is not defined outside `getJSON` method. even if you define it globally, value for it will be set via asynchronous calls. which wont reflect in `.append()` call.  correct way to this would be:

```
$(".kurir").change(function() {

var json_url = "some url here";
var _thattarif = $(this).closest(".row").find(".tarif");
$.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        alert (key); // I can see the key value
        alert (val); // I can see the val value
        _thattarif.css("background-color", "red"); 
        _thattarif.prop("disabled", false); 
        _thattarif.append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>"); 
    });  
  });
});
```